# My program is not printing what I wrote?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error

Row_style 1 draws a brick row that is "width" bricks wide using full-size bricks.  example) If width=4, then
  |____||____||____||____|

Row_style2(width) draws a brick row that is "width+1" bricks wide starting and ending with a half brick.  If width=4, then:
  |__||____||____||____||_|

The problem I'm having is that it wont print for row_style2

```
def main ():
    get_width=int(input("Enter width:" ))

    row_style1(get_width)
    row_style2(get_width+1)

def row_style1(width):
     for r in range(width):
        print('|____|', end='')
print()

def row_style2(width):
    for r in range(width):
       for c in range(1,width):
           print('|____|''|__|', end='')
print()  

main()
```

Comment: I can see one missing bracket, with properly formatted code syntax errors are much easier to spot

Comment: `get_width=int(input("Enter width:" )` is missing a `)`

Answer (score 0):

Staight forward solution would be

```
def row_style3(width):
    print('|__|', end='')

    for r in range(width-1):

        print('|____|', end='')

    print('|__|', end='')

row_style3(get_width)
```